# Cannot drop databse

Tags: mysql

I am unable to either drop database, now create the database. Following is the output. How can I fix this?

```
mysql> show databases; 
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| bisq               |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| test               |
+--------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> create database bisq;

ERROR 1007 (HY000): Can't create database 'firstblog'; database exists

mysql> drop database bisq;

ERROR 1008 (HY000): Can't drop database 'firstblog'; database doesn't exist
```

Comment: how does `bisq` turn into `firstblog`? Is this an actual cut and paste for the session?

Comment: I need some information to start figuring this out. Please run `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'datadir';`. Whatever the datadir is, go to the OS, change directory to that folder, run `ls -l`, and paste that into the question.

Comment: I think you can safely move `bisq` out of datadir. Then MySQL should allow to create the database

Answer (score -1):

try to do something like this:

```
drop schema bisq;
```

then create the database:

```
CREATE DATABASE bisq;
```

Comment: This worked perfect. I ended up creating the empty db on the slave, then stopping and starting the slave mysql. done.!